# Hiding dynamic field values in a form based on previous input

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, hide

In my code that I have written, I have two main objectives.The first is to establish the amount of hours that the user has worked, the other is to establish the overtime worked.
Now as you will be able to see in the code below, the user is able to choose from when till when did he work.

Now the question is:
How can I have my overtime fields dynamically hide the hours not relevant?

If the user has worked from 07:00 till 17:00. I want him to be able to only choose between those times in the overtime fields. I know I need to use jquery, but a bit more of a specific guide would be appreciated
Code below as follows:

```
<tr >
                    <td>From:</td>
                    <td>
                        H:<select name="from_hour" id="from_hour">
                            <option value='0'>00</option><option value='01'>01</option><option value='02'>02</option><option value='03'>03</option><option value='04'>04</option><option value='05'>05</option><option value='06'>06</option><option value='07'>07</option><option value='08'>08</option><option value='09'>09</option><option value='10'>10</option><option value='11'>11</option><option value='12'>12</option><option value='13'>13</option><option value='14'>14</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='16'>16</option><option value='17'>17</option><option value='18'>18</option><option value='19'>19</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='21'>21</option><option value='22'>22</option><option value='23'>23</option>                 </select>
                        M:<select name="from_minute" id="from_minute">
                            <option value='00'>00</option><option value='05'>5</option><option value='10'>10</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='25'>25</option><option value='30'>30</option><option value='35'>35</option><option value='40'>40</option><option value='45'>45</option><option value='50'>50</option><option value='55'>55</option>                 </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>To:</td>
                    <td>
                        H:<select name="to_hour" id="to_hour">
                            <option value='00'>00</option><option value='01'>01</option><option value='02'>02</option><option value='03'>03</option><option value='04'>04</option><option value='05'>05</option><option value='06'>06</option><option value='07'>07</option><option value='08'>08</option><option value='09'>09</option><option value='10'>10</option><option value='11'>11</option><option value='12'>12</option><option value='13'>13</option><option value='14'>14</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='16'>16</option><option value='17'>17</option><option value='18'>18</option><option value='19'>19</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='21'>21</option><option value='22'>22</option><option value='23'>23</option>                    </select>
                        M:<select name="to_minute" id="to_minute">
                            <option value='00'>00</option><option value='05'>05</option><option value='10'>10</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='25'>25</option><option value='30'>30</option><option value='35'>35</option><option value='40'>40</option><option value='45'>45</option><option value='50'>50</option><option value='55'>55</option>                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

And the overtime code:

```
<tr id="test_ovt">
                    <td>From:</td>
                    <td >
                        H:<select name="ovt_f_hour" id="ovt_f_hour">
                            <option value='0'>0</option><option value='01'>01</option><option value='02'>02</option><option value='03'>03</option><option value='04'>04</option><option value='05'>05</option><option value='06'>06</option><option value='07'>07</option><option value='08'>08</option><option value='09'>09</option><option value='10'>10</option><option value='11'>11</option><option value='12'>12</option><option value='13'>13</option><option value='14'>14</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='16'>16</option><option value='17'>17</option><option value='18'>18</option><option value='19'>19</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='21'>21</option><option value='22'>22</option><option value='23'>23</option>                  </select>
                        M:<select name="ovt_f_min" id="ovt_f_min">
                            <option value='00'>00</option><option value='05'>5</option><option value='10'>10</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='25'>25</option><option value='30'>30</option><option value='35'>35</option><option value='40'>40</option><option value='45'>45</option><option value='50'>50</option><option value='55'>55</option>                 </select>
                    </td>

                <td >To:</td>
                    <td >
                        H:<select name="ovt_t_hour" id="ovt_t_hour">
                            <option value='0'>0</option><option value='01'>01</option><option value='02'>02</option><option value='03'>03</option><option value='04'>04</option><option value='05'>05</option><option value='06'>06</option><option value='07'>07</option><option value='08'>08</option><option value='09'>09</option><option value='10'>10</option><option value='11'>11</option><option value='12'>12</option><option value='13'>13</option><option value='14'>14</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='16'>16</option><option value='17'>17</option><option value='18'>18</option><option value='19'>19</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='21'>21</option><option value='22'>22</option><option value='23'>23</option>                  </select>
                        M:<select name="ovt_t_min" id="ovt_t_min">
                            <option value='00'>00</option><option value='05'>5</option><option value='10'>10</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='25'>25</option><option value='30'>30</option><option value='35'>35</option><option value='40'>40</option><option value='45'>45</option><option value='50'>50</option><option value='55'>55</option>                 </select>
                    </td>



                </tr>
```

Another example would include:

If person X has done work from 03:00 in the morning till 16:00 in the afternoon and he would like to fill in his overtime.The overtime fields should only have values from 03:00 till 16:00 visible.

Reason being: He cannot be able to specify overtime he has worked if it does not fall between the values he listed in the worked from and to fields.

Comment: can you please give one more example like in which case overtime fields are visible and hidden.

Comment: @vijay Added another example, don't hesitate to ask for any additional info if needed

Comment: so in short; if user has selected 03:00 to 16:00 Then in `ovt_f_hour` should have values >=3 AND `ovt_t_hour` should have values < 16 . Please correct me I am wrong.

Comment: @vijayP That is correct

Comment: Hi alberto is this the thing you were looking to  http://jsfiddle.net/nadeemmnn2007/95jcLv9h/1/

Comment: or were you looking to set from hour and to hour to the same settings  as done in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nadeemmnn2007/95jcLv9h/2/

Comment: @NadeemmnnMohd Yes this (http://jsfiddle.net/nadeemmnn2007/95jcLv9h/2/) is what I am looking for, how will I make sure it adapts to the values input in the "from_hour" and "to_hour" fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please take a look at below code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
 var from_hour = $("#from_hour");
 var from_minute = $("#from_minute");
 var to_hour = $("#to_hour");
 var to_minute = $("#to_minute");

 var ovt_f_hour = $("#ovt_f_hour");
 var ovt_f_min = $("#ovt_f_min");
 var ovt_t_hour = $("#ovt_t_hour");
 var ovt_t_min = $("#ovt_t_min");

 $(from_hour).on("change",function(){
  var curr_from_hour = $(this).val();
        $(ovt_f_hour).val(curr_from_hour);
  curr_from_hour = parseInt(curr_from_hour);
       $(ovt_f_hour).find("option").prop("disabled",false).removeClass("disabled");
  $(ovt_f_hour).find("option").each(function(){
   if(parseInt($(this).val())<curr_from_hour)
    $(this).prop("disabled",true).addClass("disabled");
  });
      
 });
 
 $(to_hour).on("change",function(){
  var curr_to_hour = $(this).val();
        $(ovt_t_hour).val("00");
  curr_to_hour = parseInt(curr_to_hour);
    $(ovt_t_hour).find("option").prop("disabled",false).removeClass("disabled");
  $(ovt_t_hour).find("option").each(function(){
   if(parseInt($(this).val())>curr_to_hour)
    $(this).prop("disabled",true).addClass("disabled");
  }); 
 });
 
 $(from_minute).on("change",function(){
  var curr_from_minute = $(this).val();
        $(ovt_f_min).val(curr_from_minute);
  curr_from_minute = parseInt(curr_from_minute);
  $(ovt_f_min).find("option").prop("disabled",false).removeClass("disabled");
  $(ovt_f_min).find("option").each(function(){
   if(parseInt($(this).val())<curr_from_minute)
    $(this).prop("disabled",true).addClass("disabled");
  }); 
 });

 $(to_minute).on("change",function(){
  var curr_to_minute = $(this).val();
        $(ovt_t_min).val("00");
  curr_to_minute = parseInt(curr_to_minute);
  $(ovt_t_min).find("option").prop("disabled",false).removeClass("disabled");
  $(ovt_t_min).find("option").each(function(){
   if(parseInt($(this).val())>curr_to_minute)
    $(this).prop("disabled",true).addClass("disabled");
  }); 
 });
 
})
```

```css
.disabled{
  background-color:"#ccc";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr >
                    <td>Work From:</td>
                    <td>
                        H:<select name="from_hour" id="from_hour">
                            <option value='00'>00</option><option value='01'>01</option><option value='02'>02</option><option value='03'>03</option><option value='04'>04</option><option value='05'>05</option><option value='06'>06</option><option value='07'>07</option><option value='08'>08</option><option value='09'>09</option><option value='10'>10</option><option value='11'>11</option><option value='12'>12</option><option value='13'>13</option><option value='14'>14</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='16'>16</option><option value='17'>17</option><option value='18'>18</option><option value='19'>19</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='21'>21</option><option value='22'>22</option><option value='23'>23</option>                 </select>
                        M:<select name="from_minute" id="from_minute">
                            <option value='00'>00</option><option value='05'>5</option><option value='10'>10</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='25'>25</option><option value='30'>30</option><option value='35'>35</option><option value='40'>40</option><option value='45'>45</option><option value='50'>50</option><option value='55'>55</option>                 </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>To:</td>
                    <td>
                        H:<select name="to_hour" id="to_hour">
                            <option value='00'>00</option><option value='01'>01</option><option value='02'>02</option><option value='03'>03</option><option value='04'>04</option><option value='05'>05</option><option value='06'>06</option><option value='07'>07</option><option value='08'>08</option><option value='09'>09</option><option value='10'>10</option><option value='11'>11</option><option value='12'>12</option><option value='13'>13</option><option value='14'>14</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='16'>16</option><option value='17'>17</option><option value='18'>18</option><option value='19'>19</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='21'>21</option><option value='22'>22</option><option value='23'>23</option>                    </select>
                        M:<select name="to_minute" id="to_minute">
                            <option value='00'>00</option><option value='05'>05</option><option value='10'>10</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='25'>25</option><option value='30'>30</option><option value='35'>35</option><option value='40'>40</option><option value='45'>45</option><option value='50'>50</option><option value='55'>55</option>                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
  
  
  <tr id="test_ovt">
                    <td>Overtime From:</td>
                    <td >
                        H:<select name="ovt_f_hour" id="ovt_f_hour">
                            <option value='00'>00</option><option value='01'>01</option><option value='02'>02</option><option value='03'>03</option><option value='04'>04</option><option value='05'>05</option><option value='06'>06</option><option value='07'>07</option><option value='08'>08</option><option value='09'>09</option><option value='10'>10</option><option value='11'>11</option><option value='12'>12</option><option value='13'>13</option><option value='14'>14</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='16'>16</option><option value='17'>17</option><option value='18'>18</option><option value='19'>19</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='21'>21</option><option value='22'>22</option><option value='23'>23</option>                  </select>
                        M:<select name="ovt_f_min" id="ovt_f_min">
                            <option value='00'>00</option><option value='05'>5</option><option value='10'>10</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='25'>25</option><option value='30'>30</option><option value='35'>35</option><option value='40'>40</option><option value='45'>45</option><option value='50'>50</option><option value='55'>55</option>                 </select>
                    </td>

                <td >To:</td>
                    <td >
                        H:<select name="ovt_t_hour" id="ovt_t_hour">
                            <option value='00'>00</option><option value='01'>01</option><option value='02'>02</option><option value='03'>03</option><option value='04'>04</option><option value='05'>05</option><option value='06'>06</option><option value='07'>07</option><option value='08'>08</option><option value='09'>09</option><option value='10'>10</option><option value='11'>11</option><option value='12'>12</option><option value='13'>13</option><option value='14'>14</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='16'>16</option><option value='17'>17</option><option value='18'>18</option><option value='19'>19</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='21'>21</option><option value='22'>22</option><option value='23'>23</option>                  </select>
                        M:<select name="ovt_t_min" id="ovt_t_min">
                            <option value='00'>00</option><option value='05'>5</option><option value='10'>10</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='25'>25</option><option value='30'>30</option><option value='35'>35</option><option value='40'>40</option><option value='45'>45</option><option value='50'>50</option><option value='55'>55</option>                 </select>
                    </td>



                </tr>
  
</table>
```

Comment: Glad to know that @AlbertusBrandVenter... `:)`!

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>Worked Hours</h1>

<br />
<tr id="worked_hours" >
                    <td>From:</td>
                    <td>
                        H:<select name="from_hour" id="from_hour">
                            <option value='0'>00</option><option value='01'>01</option><option value='02'>02</option><option value='03'>03</option><option value='04'>04</option><option value='05'>05</option><option value='06'>06</option><option value='07'>07</option><option value='08'>08</option><option value='09'>09</option><option value='10'>10</option><option value='11'>11</option><option value='12'>12</option><option value='13'>13</option><option value='14'>14</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='16'>16</option><option value='17'>17</option><option value='18'>18</option><option value='19'>19</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='21'>21</option><option value='22'>22</option><option value='23'>23</option>                 </select>
                        M:<select name="from_minute" id="from_minute">
                            <option value='00'>00</option><option value='05'>5</option><option value='10'>10</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='25'>25</option><option value='30'>30</option><option value='35'>35</option><option value='40'>40</option><option value='45'>45</option><option value='50'>50</option><option value='55'>55</option>                 </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>To:</td>
                    <td>
                        H:<select name="to_hour" id="to_hour">
                            <option value='00'>00</option><option value='01'>01</option><option value='02'>02</option><option value='03'>03</option><option value='04'>04</option><option value='05'>05</option><option value='06'>06</option><option value='07'>07</option><option value='08'>08</option><option value='09'>09</option><option value='10'>10</option><option value='11'>11</option><option value='12'>12</option><option value='13'>13</option><option value='14'>14</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='16'>16</option><option value='17'>17</option><option value='18'>18</option><option value='19'>19</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='21'>21</option><option value='22'>22</option><option value='23'>23</option>                    </select>
                        M:<select name="to_minute" id="to_minute">
                            <option value='00'>00</option><option value='05'>05</option><option value='10'>10</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='25'>25</option><option value='30'>30</option><option value='35'>35</option><option value='40'>40</option><option value='45'>45</option><option value='50'>50</option><option value='55'>55</option>                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
<br />
<br />
<h1>Overtime Hours</h1>
<tr id="test_ovt">
                    <td>From:</td>
                    <td >
                        H:<select name="ovt_f_hour" id="ovt_f_hour">
                            <option value='0'>0</option><option value='01'>01</option><option value='02'>02</option><option value='03'>03</option><option value='04'>04</option><option value='05'>05</option><option value='06'>06</option><option value='07'>07</option><option value='08'>08</option><option value='09'>09</option><option value='10'>10</option><option value='11'>11</option><option value='12'>12</option><option value='13'>13</option><option value='14'>14</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='16'>16</option><option value='17'>17</option><option value='18'>18</option><option value='19'>19</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='21'>21</option><option value='22'>22</option><option value='23'>23</option>                  </select>
                        M:<select name="ovt_f_min" id="ovt_f_min">
                            <option value='00'>00</option><option value='05'>5</option><option value='10'>10</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='25'>25</option><option value='30'>30</option><option value='35'>35</option><option value='40'>40</option><option value='45'>45</option><option value='50'>50</option><option value='55'>55</option>                 </select>
                    </td>

                <td >To:</td>
                    <td >
                        H:<select name="ovt_t_hour" id="ovt_t_hour">
                            <option value='0'>0</option><option value='01'>01</option><option value='02'>02</option><option value='03'>03</option><option value='04'>04</option><option value='05'>05</option><option value='06'>06</option><option value='07'>07</option><option value='08'>08</option><option value='09'>09</option><option value='10'>10</option><option value='11'>11</option><option value='12'>12</option><option value='13'>13</option><option value='14'>14</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='16'>16</option><option value='17'>17</option><option value='18'>18</option><option value='19'>19</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='21'>21</option><option value='22'>22</option><option value='23'>23</option>                  </select>
                        M:<select name="ovt_t_min" id="ovt_t_min">
                            <option value='00'>00</option><option value='05'>5</option><option value='10'>10</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='25'>25</option><option value='30'>30</option><option value='35'>35</option><option value='40'>40</option><option value='45'>45</option><option value='50'>50</option><option value='55'>55</option>                 </select>
                    </td>



                </tr>
```

### Code

```
var items=  $('#ovt_f_hour')[0].options;
var overtimeHour = 15;
$.each(items,function(i,v){
        if(i<=overtimeHour){
        $(v).prop("disabled","disabled").css("background-color","#ccc")
        }
    });
```

### Jquery

```
$('#to_hour').on("change",function(){
var items=  $('#ovt_f_hour')[0].options;


var start_overtimeHour = $('#from_hour option:selected').text();
var end_overtime= $('#to_hour option:selected').text();
$.each(items,function(i,v){
        if(i>=start_overtimeHour&&i<=end_overtime){     
        }else{
        $(v).prop("disabled","disabled").css("background-color","#ccc");
        }
    });

var items1=  $('#ovt_t_hour')[0].options;

$.each(items1,function(i,v){
        if(i>=start_overtimeHour&&i<=end_overtime){     
        }else{
        $(v).prop("disabled","disabled").css("background-color","#ccc");
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nadeemmnn2007/95jcLv9h/4/)

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your answer. This is assuming the overtimeHour is 15 however how would I make sure that it dynamically adapts to the input done by the user? Please specify if you need more info.

Comment: The answer posted by the other user worked perfectly for me.Thank you for your contribution